# Achieving a complex grid in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

Would it be possible to achieve the attached grid in bootstrap? Each of the squares would probably be an image... or perhaps text!

I've had a go, but hit a wall when it comes to the top-left box for example that spans over two rows.

Grid:

[image]

Comment: Well I can see how to achieve this without bootstraps so I guess you can achive it with bootstraps.

Comment: Great @web-tiki, what would you recommend? Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't use bootstraps but that is very personal (I don't used it and am not very fond of it) but as you question is "is it possible" I reply "yes" as it is possible without is is possible with bootsraps. If you don't want to use bootsraps, I can help you otherwise I can't. Anyway, many people here should be able to find a bootstrap solution so don't worry about that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use nested blocks whenever you need your grid to span several rows.
Something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
        </div>        
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
</div>
```

Then you can set the height for your blocks and your grid is good to go.

Comment: Thank you very much @TwiStar, I will give this a go! For setting the height of the blocks do you recommend adding a new .css file in the css folder that readdresses the 'row' class?

Comment: I recommend having a separate stylesheet with your own custom classes that control this kind of things.

Comment: Perfect, sorry for asking so many questions, but if I was looking at the top left box for example would I put that box in a div and give it a custom class (example) 'topleft'? As the grid is responsive is it possible to mirror the width with a variable height? Thanks again TwiStar.

Comment: You should probably post that second part as its own question. You can definitely tie height to width though... With padding-bottom, and a few other specifics.

Answer (score 2):

A newbie here.
So I was learning to make nested grids when I stumble on this question.

My Rules for making nested grids:

1.The entire grid will be in parent container .row (parent wrapper)
2.Columns are always nested in columns, however all nested columns must have a .row(column wrapper) wrapper to align items horizontally e.g.:

```
<div class='col-md-12'>
    <div class='row'>This is the column wrapper.
           <div class='col-md-9'></div>
           <div class='col-md-3'></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

3.Breakpoints are very key
4.You may have to use custom css to fine tune your grid.

This is my solution to the problem:

```
  <div class='row parent-wrap'>
        <div class='col-sm-6 big-left'>Top Left big</div>
        <div class='col-sm-6 quarter-grid'>
            <div class='row top-wrap'>
            <div class='col-sm-6 top-left'>top-left</div>
            <div class='col-sm-6 top-right'>top-right</div>
         <div class='col-sm-6 bottom-left'>bottom-left</div>
       <div class='col-sm-6 bottom-right'>bottom-right</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class='col-sm-12'>
            <div class='row mid-wrap'>
          <div class='col-sm-3 mid-start'>mid-start</div>
        <div class='col-sm-6 mid-center'>mid-center</div>
        <div class='col-sm-3 mid-end'>mid-end</div>
        </div>

    <div class='col-sm-9'>
        <div class='row bottom-wrap'>
       <div class='col-sm-8 bottom-start'>bottom-start</div>
     <div class='col-sm-4 bottom-center'>bottom-center</div> 
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Rudimentary custom css:

```
 .parent-wrap{
        margin:100px;
    }

    .big-left{
        background-color: aqua;
        height:300px;
    }
    .top-left{
        background-color:black;
        height:150px;
    }
    .top-right{
        background-color: blue;
        height:150px;
    }
    .bottom-left{
        background-color:brown;
        height:150px;
    }
    .bottom-right{
        background-color:crimson;
        height:150;
    }
    .mid-start{
        background-color:grey;
        height:200px;
    }
    .mid-center{
        background-color: red;
        height:200px;
    }
    .mid-end{
        background-color: pink;
        height:400px;
    }
    .bottom-start{
        background-color:blueviolet;
        margin-left:-15px;
        height:200px;
        margin-top:-200px;
    }
    .bottom-center{
        background-color:burlywood;
        height:200px;
        margin-top:-200px;
    }
```